# How create logical condition to subtract rows for several columns in R

Tags: r

```
dataset <- structure(list(group1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    group2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), z1 = c(74L, 
    12L, 100L, 55L, 30L, 24L, 89L, 97L, 19L), z2 = c(80L, 46L, 
    88L, 20L, 3L, 49L, 34L, 86L, 97L), z3 = c(53L, 85L, 31L, 
    55L, 51L, 4L, 79L, 74L, 64L), z4 = c(46L, 30L, 68L, 3L, 40L, 
    40L, 82L, 80L, 62L), z5 = c(14L, 17L, 49L, 33L, 56L, 55L, 
    65L, 70L, 12L), z6 = c(86L, 15L, 87L, 27L, 78L, 26L, 21L, 
    69L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I need for *group1 + group2* for each variable *z* (*z1* to *z6*), from third row subtract the first row. For example(by abs):

```
z1
100-74=26
```

So same action for another variables. If any groups has only two rows, like *group1 = 1* and *group2 = 3*
then subtract from second row - the first row.
Then set condition.

```
`1.`if the difference for z1 for group1 = 1 and group2 = 1> 20, and for z2 <10, and for z3 less than 20, and for z4 more than 21, and for z5 less than 100, and for z6 less than 10, then put 1 in the result otherwise 0
`2.`if the difference for z1 for group1 = 1 and group2 = 1> 100, and for z2 <13, and less than 24 for z3, and more than 25 for z4, and less than 101 for z5, and less than 5 for z6, then put 0 in the result otherwise 1
`3.`if the difference for z1 for group1 = 1 and group2 = 3 <20, and for z2 <12, and for z3 less than 20, and for z4 more than 21, and for z5 less than 90, and for z6 less than 10, then put 0 in the result otherwise 1
```

Output

```
  group1 group2  z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z1.1 z2.1 z3.1 z4.1 z5.1
1      1      1  74 80 53 46 14 86   26    8  -22   22   35
2      1      1  12 46 85 30 17 15   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3      1      1 100 88 31 68 49 87   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4      1      2  55 20 55  3 33 27  -31   29  -51   37   22
5      1      2  30  3 51 40 56 78   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6      1      2  24 49  4 40 55 26   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
7      1      2  89 34 79 82 65 21   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
8      1      3  97 86 74 80 70 69  -78   11  -10  -18  -58
9      1      3  19 97 64 62 12 33   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  z6.1 result
1    1      1
2   NA      1
3   NA      1
4   -1      0
5   NA      0
6   NA      0
7   NA      0
8  -36      0
9   NA      0
```

How to do it?

Comment: What exactly is the condition for `z1`? I think you might have mistyped something after group2.

Comment: Group 3 set 3 only has two rows so how can you subtract the first row from the third row? What do you mean when you say For example "by abs": the differences in the expected output dataset are not absolute differences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the first part of your question:

```r
func <- function(Zs) {
  row3 <- min(length(Zs[[1]]), 3)
  newZs <- lapply(Zs, function(z) c(z[row3] - z[1], rep(NA, length(z) - 1)))
  names(newZs) <- paste0(names(Zs), ".1")
  newZs
}
grouped <- by(dataset, dataset[,c("group1","group2")],
              function(x) cbind(x, func(subset(x, select = grep("^z", names(x), value = TRUE)))))
do.call(rbind, grouped)
#   group1 group2  z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z1.1 z2.1 z3.1 z4.1 z5.1 z6.1
# 1      1      1  74 80 53 46 14 86   26    8  -22   22   35    1
# 2      1      1  12 46 85 30 17 15   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 3      1      1 100 88 31 68 49 87   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 4      1      2  55 20 55  3 33 27  -31   29  -51   37   22   -1
# 5      1      2  30  3 51 40 56 78   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 6      1      2  24 49  4 40 55 26   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 7      1      2  89 34 79 82 65 21   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 8      1      3  97 86 74 80 70 69  -78   11  -10  -18  -58  -36
# 9      1      3  19 97 64 62 12 33   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I'm not sure how to follow the logic in your `result` conditionals, hope this is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) 

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(group2) %>% 
  slice(c(1,3)) %>% 
  mutate(z1 = last(z1) - first(z1)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) ## Select odd rows
  
 df3 <- df1 %>% 
   full_join(df2, by = "id") %>% 
   select(-group1.y, -group2.y)

  df3
```

Output:

```
  group1.x group2.x z1.x z2.x z3.x z4.x z5.x z6.x id z1.y z2.y z3.y z4.y z5.y z6.y
1        1        1   74   80   53   46   14   86  1   26   80   53   46   14   86
2        1        1   12   46   85   30   17   15  2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3        1        1  100   88   31   68   49   87  3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4        1        2   55   20   55    3   33   27  4  -31   20   55    3   33   27
5        1        2   30    3   51   40   56   78  5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6        1        2   24   49    4   40   55   26  6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
7        1        2   89   34   79   82   65   21  7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
8        1        3   97   86   74   80   70   69  8    0   86   74   80   70   69
9        1        3   19   97   64   62   12   33  9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```